# Show Next/Previous without Link

Tags: posts, functions, single

I have a question.
Currently I have `<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post'); ?>` and `<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous Post'); ?>`.

Both return `Next` and `Previous` with a link.
I want it to be Next and Previous without a link. I tried removing the `%link` from the code, but the text disappeared. I want to use this code without a link because I want the built-in condition.

What should I do to render the text without the link?
Appreciate the help from the community.

Comment: There are functions you can use to check if a post has a next/previous post, but what is that "built-in condition"? What would the `Next` and `Previous` text do if they do not link to anything? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The built-in condition that I was referring to is the "Next Post" will not appear when the post is the latest and the Previous Post will not appear when the post is the oldest post.

I just want the code above to render the text only without link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the solution myself.

Just use this code, and you will get the Next/Previous post without a link:

```php
<?php previous_post('Previous Post'); ?>
<?php next_post('Next Post'); ?>
```